# Copy File to Executable Directory Recopy on Modified

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to copy a file to the same directory where the executable ends up. This means including the configuration type "RelWithDebInfo" directory with Visual Studio. Any CMake variable such as "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR" and similar don't include this folder in the path.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt copy_this.txt
    COMMENT "Copying..."
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt
)
```

The above code works but it doesn't cause the file to be recopied with it is modified. The only other solution I found where it does copy when it is to use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT copy_this.txt ...)` but it doesn't copy the file into the correct folder.

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT copy_this.txt # this expects the file to be in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt copy_this.txt
    COMMENT "Copying..."
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt
)
add_custom_target(target_copy_this.txt DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt)

add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} target_copy_this.txt)
```

Comment: maybe go with `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` ?

Comment: `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` doesn't include the config type folder, I checked all Cmake's variable, none of them do. Only one that does is `$<TARGET_FILE_PATH> but that can't be used in `add_custom_command`'s OUTPUT variable.

Comment: You need to update the question with examples that show the problem.  The first `add_custom_command` which is a build event doesn't take a `DEPENDS` field.  The second `add_custom_command` doesn't show the command and no one can tell you why it didn't copy into the correct folder.  BTW, the POST_BUILD should only run when building the target.  If the target is up to date then the command won't execute (I'm surprised you didn't get an error because it doesn't use DEPENDS).

Comment: `add_custom_command(OUTPUT )` automatically determines where the directory is, and that directory is `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` not the directory I want. So the file that needs to exist for the build to succeed is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add_custom_command needs to be updated to specify where the file needs to be copied.  In both examples the file is copied into the current working directory because the path is not specified.  Here is an example of how to copy to the home directory.

```
set(newloc ~)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${newloc}/copy_this.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt ${newloc}/copy_this.txt
    COMMENT "Copying to ${newloc}"
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/copy_this.txt
    )

add_custom_target(target_copy_this.txt ALL DEPENDS copy_this.txt)
```

It seems that you want the file to be copied to where one of the targets winds up.  In visual studio this could be `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` or `${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` depending upon what else is going on in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Using this example and setting `newloc` to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` you will get the following output:

```
cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo

CustomBuild:
Copying to C:/Users/ZZZ/Projects/test/bld/RelWithDebInfo
```

Comment: `${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}` seems to expand to `$(Configuration)` which is the Visual Studio variable for it, but I need to actual value. The file gets copied to `my_build_dir/$(Configuration)/copy_this.txt`. Not to the expected `my_build_dir/RelWithDebugInfo/copy_this.txt` or whichever configuration is currently being built.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you tried it but are just stating it won't work. In Visual Studio the variable Configuration is set to RelWithDebugInfo when you choose to build that configuration and the command line expands correctly.

Comment: Why wouldn't I try it? The `add_custom_command()` works fine, but your alternative, `configure_file()` does not. You made some edits to your answer as well. If you require to use that --config setting with cmake then that defeats the purpose of being able to select it in visual studio.

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer to show that add_custom_commad() works because of the comments stating it doesn't work.  I deleted the `configure_file()` because it didn't work.  My bad, I only tried the add_custom_command() because that was what the OP asked about.  FYI, `cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo` is a command line shortcut of opening a project in Visual Studio, selecting `RelWithDebInfo`, and hitting build.  It's great for automating the entire build process.