# How to place files next to a target's file location using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, glsl, spir-v

I want to automatically build GLSL shaders to SPIR-V and then copy them to the location of an executable target using CMake. I created the following function for this purpose:

```
function(target_shaders target_name paths_in)
    set(paths_out "")
    foreach(path_in_raw ${paths_in})
        set(path_in "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${path_in_raw}")
        set(path_out "$<TARGET_FILE:${target_name}>/../${path_in_raw}.spv")
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${path_out}
            COMMAND glslc ${path_in} -o ${path_out}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
            DEPENDS ${path_in}
            COMMENT "Compiling GLSL shader" ${path_in})
        list(APPEND paths_out ${path_out})
    endforeach()

    add_custom_target("${target_name}_shaders" DEPENDS ${paths_out})
    add_dependencies(${target_name} "${target_name}_shaders")
endfunction()
```

It takes a target name and a list of GLSL files as arguments. I invoke it like this:

```
add_executable(mini-vk main.cpp)
target_shaders(mini-vk "basic.vert;basic.frag")
```

I expected this to compile `basic.vert` and `basic.frag` to respective `.spv` files in the same directory that `mini-vk.exe` is located. Unfortunately, I get the following error instead:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_custom_command):
[cmake]   Error evaluating generator expression:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     $<TARGET_FILE:mini-vk>
[cmake] 
[cmake]   No target "mini-vk"
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first):
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:26 (target_shaders)
```

I am not sure why there is "no target `mini-vk`" as it is created on the line just above `target_shaders`.

For clarity, the code [does work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBak7.png) if I type the output path manually by changing the definition of `path_out`:

```
set(path_out "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/Debug/${path_in_raw}.spv")
```

I don't want to have to use this hack though.

Comment: The description for OUTPUT parameter of add_custom_command has following note: "New in version 3.20: Arguments to OUTPUT may use a restricted set of generator expressions. Target-dependent expressions are not permitted.". This is probably the reason why `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>` doesn't work for you: it IS [target-dependent expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#target-dependent-queries).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I missed that. This is probably the reason why it doesn't work. I will have to look for a different solution, then.

Comment: Could you post a simple `main.cpp`, `basic.vert` and `basic.frag` so I can test a solution?

Comment: related: [Copy File to Executable Directory Recopy on Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53548358/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution involving *stamp files*. Rather than using the "true" path as the `OUTPUT`, you use an empty file just for its timestamp and then go ahead and run the command you actually want with the `TARGET_FILE_DIR` generator expression.

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)

function(target_shaders name)
  set(shaders "")

  foreach (input IN LISTS ARGN)
    # Might want to add code to handle clashing names 
    # in different directories (e.g. ./basic.vert and
    # ./subdir/basic.vert)
    cmake_path(GET input FILENAME stem)
    cmake_path(ABSOLUTE_PATH input
               BASE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
               NORMALIZE)
    add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT "${stem}.stamp"
      COMMAND Vulkan::glslc "${input}" -o "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${name}>/${stem}.spv"
      COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch "${stem}.stamp"
      DEPENDS "${input}"
    )
    list(APPEND shaders "${stem}.stamp")
  endforeach ()

  add_custom_target("${name}.shaders" DEPENDS ${shaders})
  add_dependencies("${name}" "${name}.shaders")
endfunction()

# Just to test changing the output directory
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY bin)

add_executable(mini-vk main.cpp)
target_shaders(mini-vk basic.vert "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/basic.frag")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me. This could be since I am using MSVC with Visual Studio generators, but I'm not sure. I was able to use `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` instead, though.

Comment: @janekb04 - _In what way_ did it not work? I'm happy to help fix it if you can provide repro steps.